# Prevent/Supress showing popup of Wifi Connection asking for password on terminal command

Tags: command-line, wireless

Im working on a C++ program that can execute terminal commands for me, and one of its functions is wifi manipulation (connect, disconnect, forget). Right now I am trying to execute a wifi connection command in the terminal using the ff.:

```
nmcli device wifi connect <wifiName> password <password>
```

Above works fine in the terminal when the password is right, but it shows a popup asking for the correct password when the supplied password is wrong:

[image: Wifi Connection popup after executing terminal command]

Is there a way I can prevent the popup from happening, so my program doesn't pause indefinitely until I close it manually? Or is there a better command to handle wifi connection given the wifi name and password?

Comment: You may 'test' the key (password) before running the nmcli command. this can be done with `wpa_supplicant` or `iwconfig` and their return codes

Comment: I'm still pretty new to working with linux commands in general, could you give a small sample commadn on how to achieve this? I assume I'd test iwconfig first then if the return code is good then I can proceed to the original command above?

Comment: are you running a script? if the pw is failed and if pop up is not generated the next commands in the script does not require Internet connection?

Comment: @PRATAP no this is sent from a C++ program that creates the string and sends to the terminal. Right now the program stops since there is a popup, which I'd like to suppress/prevent from showing.

Comment: You should probably be using `libnm` or the dbus API rather than shelling out to `nmcli` - see for example [When to use libnm](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/usage.html) and [Newbie: how to talk to NM by C or C++? Need some hints](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2010-December/msg00088.html)

Answer (score 1):

from `man nmcli`

you can use below command.

but you may require few more details other than just `ssid` and `password`

```
nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlp2s0 ssid H con-name PRATAP2 +802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt WPA-PSK +802-11-wireless-security.psk 50251919
```

the details here I used other than `ssid` and `password` are

```
ifname
+802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt
```

the `nmcli` command above will not popup as in your Question, It will popup a msg like in this gif file below which will not stop your work flow if the password is wrong...

My required details are:

```
ifname is wlp2s0
SSID is `H`
password is 50251919
wireless security key is WPA-PSK
```

So the command to add this connection with the password is as above..

Observe the below gif at the end.. when I entered wrong password.. It did not disturb the running process.. Instead It Just Showed a Notification at the top, If we want to enter the password again, we can click it other wise Ignore..

***Note: This method works if there are no connections exist.***

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: It just adds a connection and doesn't actually try to connect, no matter if the password is correct or not, or if the `nmcli con show` list is empty or not. When I do `nmcli con up PRATAP2` (using your connection name for clarity) it pops up a password dialog that this was supposed to prevent.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus the post is quite old.. so I didn't catch up your comment well.. but the gif is satisfactory??

Comment: No. I followed the GIF. After both nmcli commands nothing happens and nothing pops up. When I use the nm-applet in xfce or good 'ol `nmcli d w c` I do see the transparent popups

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](https://vitux.com/disable-connectivity-checking-on-ubuntu-for-public-wifi-captive-portals/) is described how to turn off this WiFi popup, I think it may help. It is also described the procedure from command line.